# How to outsource modals into another html file using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a lot of modals in my app and I want to outsource these modals into a seperate file. A modal looks like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="configurationModal.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>Configuration</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <label>Host: </label><input ng-model="hostName"><br>
            <label>Port: </label><input ng-model="port">
            <div>
                <label>CouchDB</label><br>
                <label>Host: </label><input ng-model="dbProperties.dbHostName"><br>
                <label>Port: </label><input ng-model="dbProperties.dbPort"><br>
                <label>User: </label><input ng-model="dbProperties.dbUser"><br>
                <label>Password: </label><input type="password" ng-model="dbProperties.dbPassword"><br>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn primary-btn btn2" ng-click="cancel()">OK</button>
        </div>
</script>
```

In my js-file I'm attaching it like this:

```
$scope.configureFactory = function () {
    $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'configurationModal.html',
        backdrop: true,
        windowClass: 'configuration-modal',
        controller: function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {

            //......
```

Now I just want to put these modal templates into another html-file but my main `index.html`.
I have already tried to reference to another html file in my index.html like:

`<link type="text/html" href="modals.html"/>`

and I've tried using ng-include:

`<div ng-include="'configurationModal.html'"></div>`, but nothing works.

Always getting:
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Fred/foo/foo2/foo3/src/configurationModal.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

How can I outsource my modals and still attache them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $templateRequest as below...

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $templateRequest, $sce, $compile){
    // Make sure that no bad URLs are fetched. If you have a static string like in this
    // example, you might as well omit the $sce call.
    var templateUrl = $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl('nameOfTemplate.html');

    $templateRequest(templateUrl).then(function(template) {
        // template is the HTML template as a string

        // Let's put it into an HTML element and parse any directives and expressions
        // in the code. (Note: This is just an example, modifying the DOM from within
        // a controller is considered bad style.)
        $compile($("#my-element").html(template).contents())($scope);
    }, function() {
        // An error has occurred here
    });
});
```